# Azure table backup retrieve more than 1000 rows

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I hope somebody can help me to debug this issue.

I have the following script

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService,ListGenerator
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from datetime import date
from datetime import *




def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("instet data:" + str(item) + "into table:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_or_replace_entity(tb_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=tb_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()

for tb in tbs_out:
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(table_name=tb.name, fail_on_exist=False)
    #first query
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb.name,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

this code will check the table in `storageA` copy them and create the same table in `StorageB`, and thanks to the `marker` I can have the `x_ms_continuation` token if I have more than 1000 rows per requests.

Goes without saying that this works just fine as it is.

But yesterday I was trying to make some changes to the code as follow:

`If in storageA I have a table name TEST, I storageB I want to create a table named TEST20210930, basically the table name from storageA + today date`

This is where the code start breaking down.

```
table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
query_size = 100

#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("instet data:" + str(item) + "into table:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_or_replace_entity(tb_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=tb_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()
print(tbs_out)

for tb in tbs_out:
    table = tb.name + today
    print(target_connection_string)
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(table_name=table, fail_on_exist=False)

    #first query
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(table,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

What happens here is that the code runs up to the query_size limit but than fails saying that the table was not found.

I am a bit confused here and maybe somebody can help to spot my error.

Please if you need more info just ask

Thank you so so so much.

HOW TO REPRODUCE:
In azure portal create 2 storage account. StorageA and StorageB.

In storage A create a table and fill it with data, over 100 (based on the query_size.
Set the configuration Endpoints. `table_service_out` = storageA and `table_storage_in` = StorageB

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: Hi Gaurav. I just updated my post with the sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the following line of code:

```
data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=tb_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
```

If you notice, `tb_name` is the name of the table in your target account which is obviously not present in your source account. Because you're querying from a table that does not exist, you're getting this error.

To fix this, you should also pass the name of source table to `queryAndSaveAllDataBySize` and use that when querying entities in that function.

**UPDATE**

Please take a look at code below:

```
table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
query_size = 100

#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(source_table_name, target_table_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("instet data:" + str(item) + "into table:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_or_replace_entity(target_table_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=source_table_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(source_table_name, target_table_name, data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()
print(tbs_out)

for tb in tbs_out:
    table = tb.name + today
    print(target_connection_string)
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(table_name=table, fail_on_exist=False)

    #first query
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb.name, table,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

Comment: Yes that true. But what I have in mind. when I `create` the table in the storageB, I want that table to have the name of table in storageA + Today date. As this whole code will run once a week, I want to have clear to which date that backup is related to. And this is my main issue and I have not clue how to solve this. If in storageA I have a table name `Table` I want the same content to be copied over to a table in storageB with name `Table20210930`

Comment: 2min and I will update my post with the new code. Which it does exactly what I want, but fails after the query_size reaches the threshold

Comment: That's completely understandable but there's a logical flaw in your code. The table specified by `tb_name` variable does not exist in your source storage account (storage A). That's what I am trying to say here.

Comment: Updated my answer with modified code. Please take a look at it. HTH.

Comment: Yessss that worked. omg thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you. May god give you a Ferrari brother.